# Should we seperate DataModel and Controller Model in .NET CORE Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I saw some projects Data Model and Controller Model is seperated but some of them are using common model. Why do we need to sepereate these or we do not need?

Comment: Could you maybe add links to the projects that you saw for each approach? Wether you need to separate data and controller model really depends on your specific use case and as far as I'm aware there's no specific guide line here. It will be easier to discuss the topic based on a specific example, I think

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide a sample of the code from your problem so we can help you better.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By "DataModel", I'm taking you to mean the entity class you're persisting with something like Entity Framework Core, and by "Controller Model", I'm taking you to mean a view model, or the thing that's passed between the view and the controller.

Given those assumptions, simply, yes. Good object-oriented code should follow SOLID. The first letter of that acronym stands for single-responsibility, and it's probably first for a reason. Classes should do one thing and do it well. As soon as a class starts having too much knowledge of the domain or starts taking on concerns it's not principally charged with, then you getting buggy, horrible code that is next to impossible to maintain.

Based on this, the responsibility of your entity class is to represent a set of persisted data. That is all. As such, it's almost assuredly going to be incompatible with what you need to do in your controllers/views. If you just start adding stuff to the entity class for the purpose of the controller/view, then now you've got a single class that essentially serving two masters. It blurs the line between what's for persistence and what's for display/validation/etc. in a view.

The correct thing to do is to create a view model: a class that is responsible specifically for serving the needs of the view. Then, you can keep persistence logic safely in one class and view logic encapsulated away safely in another class, and just map data back and forth between the two.

Comment: To me, all time data model and view model would be consıstent so I would not add extra Model class. Thanks for reply.